# Finding Prime Numbers But No Output

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that will find and output all the prime numbers from 1-100 and I am able to build the program ,however no actual prime numbers are outputted.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    for (int j = i-1; j >= 2; j--)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            break;
        else if (j == 1)
            cout << i;
        else if (i % j == 0)
            break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Pop quiz for you:

Given the following loop condition:

```
for (int j = i-1; j >= 2; j--)
```

I am specifically referring to the "`j >= 2`" part that's required for the loop to iterate; so your pop quiz question is as follows:

Do you think that the following `if` statement will ever evaluate to `true`?

```
     if (j == 1)
```

And if you believe that `j` can possibly reach the value of 1, when the loop condition is `j >= 2`, can you explain how that would happen?

Doesn't seem, to me, that it can ever happen, does it? And this is why your code does not generate any output.

Comment: That makes sense, I changed (j==1) to (j==2) and it worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you've changed `j==1` to `j==2`, you also need to add another `if` to judge whether the number could be divided by `2`, I think that will output the correct prime number.